# Windows Explorer search command with exact file name match

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-search

How to filter the result to the single result item only, not "any" similar items.

Using [Windows Explorer Search syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference)

Sample file name: `config.config`

Search string in Windows Explorer: `name:config ext:config`

[image: Full name sample]
[image: explicit sample with extension]

Wanted: one single item in result like the syntax is working with "add" instead of "or" methode.

Comment: Did you try to use quotes for the name part of the search and `filename` instead of name?

Comment: `filename`is no syntax keyword. Quotes are only a needed issue in case of space char between words. Anyway I tried but the result is the same.

Comment: It's listed as a syntax keyword for `kind:everything` just like `ext` is in the document you linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the name:= filter for this, like so:

```
name:=Foo.bar
```

Note the equals character, this will give you an exact match.

Comment: Tested! The result becomes as expected. syntax `name:=config.config` > `config.config` file found. Very interesting to have double operator usage in a Microsoft system. Not clean and overhad but it is like it is. Thank you!