# Win 10 search box in explorer: how to restrict search to only filenames

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

When I search for a keyword "foo" by typing it in the Windows 10 File Explorer search box (top right corner) in a folder it seems to search (correct me if I am wrong please!) within filenames as well as within file contents (for pdf, doc etc.) files.

But in certain cases I would like to only look for files that contain the keyword "foo". Is there an operator etc. that will allow me to do that?

Alternatively, are there any plugins etc. (maybe 3rd party) that can allow such tweaking to the Windows search box?

Comment: Discussions in this question introduced "name:=" as some kind of filter when searching in file explorer.
https://superuser.com/questions/1338187/windows-explorer-search-command-with-exact-file-name-match

Answer (score 2):

Use this [AQS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference) query:

```
filename:<filename>
```

Example:

```
filename:foo
```

Note that on non-indexed locations, the file content search is disabled by default.

**Reference:** ["Search file names only, not the contents"](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-contents-of-any-file-windows-search-indexing/)